# EXTJS 5.1.1: Paging toolbar - IE8 - Layout Run Failed

Tags: javascript, extjs, layout, internet-explorer-8, extjs5

I'm encountring a problem with the paging toolbar of EXTJS 5.1.1 which raises an Layout Run failed in IE 8. it's working fine on chrome and firefox ..
when I remove the toolbar, my grid is fine.

Here is my code:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.overview.List', {
extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
alias: 'widget.overviewlist',

requires: [
    'Ext.form.field.ComboBox',
    'Ext.form.field.Date',
    'Ext.button.Button',
    'Ext.grid.column.Action',
    'Ext.grid.View',
    'Ext.grid.column.Date',
    'Ext.form.field.Number',
    'Ext.form.field.TextArea',
    'Ext.toolbar.Paging',
    'Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing'
],

title: 'KPIs Overview',
titleAlign: 'center',
store: 'Overviews',
itemId: 'overview-grid',
width: 900,
layout:'fit',
height: 650,
dockedItems:
        [
            {
                xtype:'toolbar',
                dock: 'top',
                autoScroll: true,
                itemId  : 'toolbar',
                items   : [
                    {
                        xtype: 'combo',
                        itemId:'unitCombo',
                        fieldLabel: 'Unit',
                        labelWidth: 30,
                        width: 120,
                        margin: '0 0 0 0',
                        store: 'Units',
                        queryMode: 'local',
                        displayField: 'unit',
                        valueField: 'unit'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'combo',
                        itemId: 'rcCombo',
                        fieldLabel: 'RC',
                        labelWidth: 25,
                        width: 115,
                        margin: '0 10 0 10',
                        store: 'Rcs',
                        queryMode: 'local',
                        displayField: 'rc',
                        valueField: 'rc'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'combo',
                        itemId:'appCombo',
                        fieldLabel: 'Application',
                        labelWidth: '50px',
                        margin: '0 10 0 0',
                        store: 'Applications',
                        queryMode: 'local',
                        displayField: 'name',
                        valueField: 'id'
                    },
                    '-',
                    {
                        xtype    : 'datefield',
                        itemId   : 'fromCombo',
                        name     : 'fromCombo',
                        format   : 'F-Y',
                        fieldLabel: 'From',
                        labelWidth: 30,
                        width: 130
                    },
                    {
                        xtype    : 'datefield',
                        itemId   : 'toCombo',
                        name     : 'toCombo',
                        format   : 'F-Y',
                        fieldLabel: 'To',
                        labelWidth: 20,
                        width: 120
                    },
                    {
                        name:'searchButton',
                        itemId:'searchButton',
                        text:'Search'
                    },
                    {
                        name:'resetButton',
                        itemId:'resetButton',
                        text:'Reset'
                    }

                ]
            },
             **{
                xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
                height: 60,
                pageSize: 12,
                store: 'Overviews',
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'combobox',
                        itemId: 'pagerCombo',
                        width: 120,
                        fieldLabel: 'Nb. rows',
                        labelWidth: 60,
                        editable: false,
                        store: [
                            12,
                            24,
                            36,
                            "All"
                        ]
                    },
                    '->',
                    {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        itemId:'xlsxExport',
                        href: '#',
                        iconCls: 'xlsx-button',
                        scale: 'large',
                        autoWidth: true,
                        autoHeight: true,
                        tooltip:'Export to excel'
                    }
                ]
            }** 
        ],
columns: [

        {
          .......
        },
        {
            xtype: 'gridcolumn',
            ........
        }
    ],

        plugins: [
            {
                ptype: 'rowediting',
                pluginId: 'rowEditor',
                clicksToEdit: 2,
                autoCancel: false
            }
        ]
});
```

The toolbar is working fine, but the pagingtoolbar is not.. !
I tried with dock: 'bottom', dock: 'top' and without, it's the same error on IE ...

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Are you running IE8 in standards mode or not? Also, what is the doctype?

Comment: @DrakeES Yes, IE8 standards mode. the doctypes are:  
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!--[if IE]>
          <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<![endif]-->

Comment: Those are meta headers, not [`doctype`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_type_declaration).

Comment: @DrakeES ah sorry !  <!DOCTYPE html> this ??

Comment: @DrakeES no news? :(

Comment: No, I'm not paid for it, sorry :)

Comment: i didn't mean that ... sorry !! i'm just stuck with this problem that i couldn't resolve... thanks any way..

Comment: I think the problem is from the neptune theme, I changed the theme given with the 5.1.1 version the the one of 5.0.1, and the "Layout Run failed" didn't apear ... I don't know what do i have to change in the theme..